# SSRS Reports location when being deployed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm just helping out while our regular SSRS guy is away and having an issue.
There is currently a very large report that's being generated. The subscription settings for this report is to ftp the report. The Subscription status for the report currently says "Processing delivery...". I assume this to mean that it finished generating and is now trying to send the file to the ftp location. I can see that the file is there in the ftp folder but the size is still 0kb. It has been saying "Processing delivery..." for a long time now.

My question is: Is there a location (folder or sql table) I can check to see if ssrs is actually doing something? I assume it would create temporary file somewhere locally first before sending it on its way.

Answer (score 2):

Check the ExecutionLog views in the ReportServer DB of your SQL Instance. There are three views which show everything from the requested format to start time, complete times, and parameters used. Take a look at the time difference between start and complete for previous runs and compare it to the running time of the current report whose complete time will be null if it is still processing.

For bonus points: setup a SSRS report based on the view and set a subscription for daily email delivery. This saves a TON of time when troubleshooting reports where users can't tell you the parameters they use or the morning reports are empty, etc.

Also, funny as it sounds, you might want to check the free space on the server that the report is output to. With no free space the report will show processing delivery for a long time. If it's FTP and you don't have control of the FTP server, still might be worth the quick phone call.